# Is there a way to maintain context permanently ? such as an API key

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-es, facebook-chatbot

I'm using API.AI with a backend in Golang to create a chatbot that queries an API. This API needs a API key.

This API key is user specific, it does not reply the same answer for different users.

I understand that context in API.AI can persist informations but it lasts only for a session.

Is there a way to memorize indefinitely (more or less) an information ?

Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

API.AI doesn't store most dynamic data beyond the session as you've already indicated.  For data as secure as API or authentication keys I'd recommend a secure database or datastore outside of API.AI and using user IDs for the platform's your working with through API.AI to connect the user to their API/authentication key (API.AI passes through information about where the request is coming from the `originalRequest` attribute of the JSON sent with every [webhook request](https://api.ai/docs/fulfillment#request)).

For instance you can retrieve the ID of a user who accesses your API.AI agent through the Google Assistant with `originalRequest.data.user.user_id`, Slack users with `originalRequest.data.user` and Facebook users with `originalRequest.data.sender.id`